# How to remove one graph line from a graph and not all of them

Tags: java, graph

So I have a method that graphs data from an arraylist, which contains names and there ranking for different decades. Every time the user types in a different name and pushes the "Graph" button on the GUI, the name will be graphed according to it's ranking for each decade. However, when I want to go clear the graph I want to be able to clear one graph line(each graph line is just one name's info) at a time when I push "Clear One" button. I have a clear all method, which looks likes this,

```
public void clearAll()
{
  //Adds code to clear all names from the graphArray
      graphArray.clear();

      //Calls repaint() to update the graph
      repaint();
}
```

and this belongs to my "Clear All" button. This works to clear all the different graph lines at the same time, but how can I clear just one at a time, specifically I want to remove the first graph line they entered first. So if the user enters 4 names(like sam, bill, bob, john), I want my clear one button to remove the oldest named entered which would be sam. Then the next time the button is hit, it would remove bill. So is there something like the

```
.clear()
```

that can do this or what do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your data is stored in an `ArrayList` called `graphArray`, you can call `graphArray.remove(0)` to delete the first element in that list, assuming that the first element is the oldest value.

This can easily be found using the API for `ArrayList` found here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html